# JPA embedded composite primary key and auto generation of ID

Tags: jpa, primary-key, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I have a number of tables that have this general layout (note that the SQL here is not complete - it's the minimum to illustrate the question):-

```
table1
------
int ID auto_increment,
table2_ID int, -- Foreign key
table3_ID int, -- Foreign key
prop1 varchar,
prop2 int;
```

`table1` has a many-to-1 identifying relationship with `table2`, `table2` has a many-to-1 identifying relationship with `table3`, etc.

NetBeans creates entity class content similar to this for all tables:-

```
table1.java
-----------
@EmbeddedId
table1PK key;
@Column(name = "prop1")
String prop1;
@Column(name = "prop2")
int prop2;

table1PK.java
-------------
@Column(name = "ID")
int ID;
@Column(name = "table2_ID")
int table2ID;
@Column(name = "table3_ID")
int table3ID;
```

As indicated in the table definition I want the unique ID for each table to be auto-generated, and I want to use `@TableGenerator` to do it.

If I do the following in the PK classes, a) will it work and b) will it be safe?

```
table1PK.java
-------------
@TableGenerator(name="table1ID", table="id_generator", pkColumnName="gen_name", valueColumnName="gen_value", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1 )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "table1ID" )
@Column(name = "ID")
int ID;
@Column(name = "table2_ID")
int table2ID;
@Column(name = "table3_ID")
int table3ID;
```

I've added the table generator code to one of the PK classes and the project builds and deploys without errors, but NetBeans is giving a warning for ID in the PK table:-

```
GeneratedValue annotation should only be used for Id field
```

Although part of a composite primary key, the field is an ID field on the underlying table.

Comment: If the ID is unique and immutable, then it should be your primary key. Adding additional properties to make it a composite PK will only make things much harder. Avoid composite keys like the plague.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, though I disagree with your view.  The 'additional properties' in the composite key are the unique IDs from the related tables and they enforce relationship constraints on the data. Removing these foreign keys from the composite primary key would subvert the relational design of the DB and would undermine data integrity. Composite keys are a core feature of relational database design and should not be removed just because they might require a little extra work on the part of the developer.

Comment: What do they enforce? The database will check that the tuple [ID, FK1 FK2] is unique. That will always be true, whatever the value of FK1 and FK2, since ID is already unique. What additional integrity do you gain by adding them in the PK?

Comment: Identity. If you remove them from the primary key then the relationship ceases to be an identifying relationship.  None of this is relevant to the question that I asked though, which is how do I do it, not should I do it.